# Adding commands to windows speech recognition using SAPI 5.4 with C#

Tags: c#, macros, speech-recognition, sapi

I want to know how can I add commands to windows 7 shared speech recognition using SAPI 5.4 in C#. There is already a Microsoft application named WSRMacros, but I should do it programmatically by myself.
Any help and explanation would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an application that uses [`System.Speech.Recognizer.SpeechRecognizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This loads the shared recognizer, which starts Windows Speech Recognition.

Create your grammars, and off you go!

Comment: Thanks Eric, I was waiting for you to answer me. Actually I want to add the commands to widows speech recognition application in a way that even after I closed my application they would remain in windows speech application, so I think I need to do that with SpeechLib not System.Speech. and I don't want to replace the default grammmar by the new ones. So What do you think?
By the way I know that this is my mistake that I couldn't clarify these things in my original question.

Comment: Adding new commands to the shared recognizer won't replace the commands in the default grammar.  But your application has to stay running (even in the background or in a system tile, but not as a service) for your commands to be recognized.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I noticed that but I thought maybe there is another (hard) way to make them remain into the shared recognizer memory.

Comment: @JimmyHarford Even if there *was* some way to make the grammars stick around, what would happen once your program had exited?